# How to know what package yum would install or update

Tags: yum

I know, running command yum update package_name will list all the package that will install or update along with main package. I want to know if their is any other way we can find  the same result and not use yum update or install.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

`yum check-update package_name`

Implemented so you could know if your machine had any updates that needed to be applied without running it interactively.

You can run it without `package_name` and it will show the list of all available updates.

`yum check-update`

Answer (score 2):

`yum` has been designed specifically to handle such tasks. I'm not sure why would you try to avoid it, since it's pretty good package manager.

You can list all outdated packages with:

```
yum list updates
```

You can update packages with:

```
yum -y update
```